nfc-mfclassic does not allow writing on a tag
Trying to copy an NFC tag. I did it some years ago without difficulties but did not manage to do it again. I think that the problem comes from this command:
nfc-mfclassic W a net-security.dmp

which is not writing on the tag. Here are more informations (NB: I put some * for the UID and for the key).

First I read the tag I want to copy:
$ nfc-list -v

nfc-list uses libnfc 1.8.0
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
1 ISO14443A passive target(s) found:
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04  
* UID size: single
* bit frame anticollision supported
      UID (NFCID1): * * * *                 
     SAK (SEL_RES): 08  
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-4
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 18092

Fingerprinting based on MIFARE type Identification Procedure:
 * MIFARE Classic 1K
 * MIFARE Plus (4 Byte UID or 4 Byte RID) 2K, Security level 1
 * SmartMX with MIFARE 1K emulation


then I made a dump of the tag (the key is in the file extended-std.keys):
$ mfoc -f extended-std.keys -O net-security.dmp


then I copy the dump on a blank tag:
$ nfc-mfclassic W a U**** net-security.dmp

Attempting to use specific UID: 0x2e 0x9f 0xd7 0xa0
NFC reader: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
Found MIFARE Classic card:
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04  
       UID (NFCID1): * * * *  
      SAK (SEL_RES): 08  
RATS support: no
Guessing size: seems to be a 1024-byte card
Sent bits:     50  00  57  cd  
Sent bits:     40 (7 bits)
Received bits: a (4 bits)
Sent bits:     43  
Received bits: 0a  
Card unlocked
Writing 64 blocks |................................................................|
Done, 64 of 64 blocks written.



All seems ok but the copy of the tag is not working.

Just to see, I made a dump of the copy of the tag.
$ mfoc -f extended-std.keys -O net-security_copy.dmp

The custom key 0x**** has been added to the default keys
Found Mifare Classic 1k tag
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
    ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04  
* UID size: single
* bit frame anticollision supported
       UID (NFCID1): * * * * 
      SAK (SEL_RES): 08  
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-4
* Not compliant with ISO/IEC 18092

Fingerprinting based on MIFARE type Identification Procedure:
* MIFARE Classic 1K
* MIFARE Plus (4 Byte UID or 4 Byte RID) 2K, Security level 1
* SmartMX with MIFARE 1K emulation
Other possible matches based on ATQA & SAK values:

Try to authenticate to all sectors with default keys...
Symbols: '.' no key found, '/' A key found, '\' B key found, 'x' both keys found
(swip)
Sector 00 - Found   Key A: ****         Found   Key B: ****
Sector 01 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 02 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 03 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 04 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 05 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 06 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 07 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 08 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 09 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 10 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 11 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 12 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 13 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 14 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff
Sector 15 - Found   Key A: ffffffffffff Found   Key B: ffffffffffff



The key is ok only for the sector 0. The dump for the copy of the tag is different of the original tag. I think that during the copy, there is a problem but I don't know which.
If someone has an idea....

you're not really giving anyone any indication of what goes wrong. This is like calling a car shop, saying "my car doesn't drive me to work", and then hanging up. You will have to define: which car, what does it do instead, does it show anything or make any special noise…

Show us the actual command, its output, and the system logs dealing with NFC.

Both of you are right. I wrote again my question.
